# Why this regex doesn't catch all integers?

Tags: regex

Why this regex doesn't catch all integers between operator signs?

```
(^|[-+*\/\^])(\d+)([-+*\/\^]|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/UeepIz/1

Comment: What you want to capture?

Comment: Because of the consuming groups. Use `(?<![^-+*\/^])(\d+)(?![^-+*\/^])`, lookarounds.

Comment: It's best to include all the details of your question here, instead of sending us to another site to see the problem.   (You can include the link also, but only as an add-on).  Also, explain what you want to get and would you are getting instead.  for example, do you want the minus signs include with the numbers, and do you want the "1.5" included or excluded?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think it's the same thing? 

The construction (\d+)([-+*\/\^]) means to find one or more digits followed by one of the symbols -+*/^

And the construction (\d+)(?![^-+*\/^]) means to find one or more digits after which there are symbols other than those that do not match -+*/^ i.e. the same symbols -+*/^